# AWS Elastic Cache, Redis Cluster & Spring Cache Annotations

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, aws-sdk, jedis

I have setup spring boot using cache annotations as seen below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableElastiCache({@CacheClusterConfig(name = "prod-cache", expiration = 259200)})
@Profile("!local")
public class ClusterCache {}
```

This works perfectly. In this setup I create a cache named "prod-cache" without "Cluster Mode enabled (Scale Out)" enabled; as seen below:

[image: This setting is ok]

If I create an elastic cache with "Cluster Mode enabled (Scale Out)" enabled; and choosing two shards (and 0 replicas for each shard) I receive following error from my application:

> Caused by:
>   com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.model.CacheClusterNotFoundException:
>   CacheCluster not found: prod-cache (Service: AmazonElastiCache; Status
>   Code: 404; Error Code: CacheClusterNotFound; Request ID:
>   2e147019-bc6c-11e6-b7db-19f8baf0d46e)     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1378)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:924)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:702)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:454)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:416)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:365)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient.doInvoke(AmazonElastiCacheClient.java:2899)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient.invoke(AmazonElastiCacheClient.java:2869)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.elasticache.AmazonElastiCacheClient.describeCacheClusters(AmazonElastiCacheClient.java:1492)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.ElastiCacheFactoryBean.createInstance(ElastiCacheFactoryBean.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.ElastiCacheFactoryBean.createInstance(ElastiCacheFactoryBean.java:36)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.config.annotation.ElastiCacheCacheConfigurer.clusterCache(ElastiCacheCacheConfigurer.java:69)
>     ... 89 common frames omitted

Here is the setting that causes error:

[image: Setting that does not work]

Comment: Note: If I switch from Redis to Memcached; same settings works again. So I guess it is related with AWS SDK, spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure.

Comment: Note-2: I also had problems with @cacheput annotation. It works with local cache; but it does not work in memcached impl. of aws. I switched to xmemcached; it works like a charm. At the end I decided to go with xmemcached; and use my own auto-discovery impl.

Comment: I am still not able to run this. I am using AWS - memcached and same configuration as yours. I have a question here - Since I am running locally, how does my application know where is my cache located? Earlier I was using ip address i.e 127.0.0.1 along with the bastion host.